# How to retrive a cell value in groovy

Tags: groovy

How to access a specific cell data in a CSV file using groovy.

```
|      | Col1 | Col2 |
|------|------|------|
| Row1 | 10   | 20   |
| Row2 | 30   | 40   |
| Row3 | 50   | 60   |
```

In the above table, how would I retrieve 60? Any method available?

code:

```
def csv = new File("C:/SoapUIWorkspace/TestData.csv") 
def lines = csv.readLines() 
lines.each{ log.info it }
```

Comment: How do you know which row to look in the data?

Comment: @injecteer
This is what i've been trying at,

def csv = new File("C:/SoapUIWorkspace/TestData.csv")
def lines = csv.readLines()
lines.each{
 log.info it
}

But the above is displaying the entire line. Not sure where to split and print the cell item

Comment: @UmeshKumar, do you have column names in the csv file?  Is the csv data fixed?

Comment: @Rao
No. As an example, I'm using only 3 rows and 3 columns. In real time, it's volatile. Column names can be used as per the example specified above i.e. Col1 and col2..

Comment: Where is the 3rd column? In case of volatile, how do you which row data to be retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a proper CSV-file, I'd use something like:

```
def csv = new File("C:/SoapUIWorkspace/TestData.csv") 
int lineNo = 0
csv.splitEachLine( ';' ){ cols ->
  String col2 = cols[ 1 ]
  if( 3 == lineNo ) doSomethingWith60( col2 )
  lineNo++
}
```